# find newPoint with nVectorLength to the left of sourcePoint

Tags: math, lua, rotation, geometry

I've been pulling my hair out over this one...
I am trying to find a newPoint that is always situated nVectorLength to the left of a sourcePoint.
**Note:** x,y,z values are never static.

**I have two points:**

1. sourcePoint(x,y,z)
2. endPoint(x,y,z) where the source-point is moving to. 
   *- Can be used to find out where the source-point is facing to (aka up-direction)*
   <del>*- Unsure if this point is needed when you have x,y,z values of sourcePoint.*</del>

**The example below with VectorLength = 22 explains this better:**

[image]

### **NOTE:** red point is drawn to the right, this should be to the left ofc.
 My mistake.

I tried rotating the blue point 90 degrees first, but my code is wrong:

```
function rotatePoint(point, center, angle)

   angle = (angle) * (math.pi/180)
   local rotatedX = math.cos(angle) * (point.x - center.x) - math.sin(angle) * (point.y - center.y) + center.x
   local rotatedY = math.sin(angle) * (point.x - center.x) + math.cos(angle) * (point.y - center.y) + center.y
   local rotatedZ = math.sin(angle) * (point.x - center.x) + math.cos(angle) * (point.y - center.y) + center.z

   local newPoint = {x = rotatedX, y = rotatedY, z = rotatedZ}
   return newPoint
end
```

I havent come to the part where I set it to nVectorLength, but I'm hoping someone can give me a working example of how to do the rotation + length part.

Comment: There is no intrinsic left and right in 3D space. You need another vector as a reference (e.g. the up-direction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume a 2D space: Your source (green), end (blue), and new (red) points lie in the xy-plane.  There is a unit vector (0, 0, 1) perpendicular to the plane pointing out at you.  Positive rotations from the x-axis follow the right hand rule: counterclockwise.

If that's the case, then this is an easy problem.

1. calculate the unit vector from the source to the end point.  I'll assume you know how to do that.
2. Rotate the unit vector 90 degrees in the *clockwise* direction.
3. Multiply the rotated unit vector by the length and add to the source point coordinates to get the new point coordinates.

All this holds true in a 3D space as well.  You'll just need to transform from the 3D plane that you wish into the 2D plane, do the calculation, and transform back.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I managed to fix it for the x,y values. I have still no idea how to rotate the z value tho...

Comment: You mean how to do it for a general plane in 3D space?  Nothing more than one or more rotations.  It's easy if you understand something about vectors and linear transformations.